# How to replace 0 with N/A

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace

In my case statement, I'm using `0` if the value is `NULL`. Now I want to replace `0` with `N/A`. I've tried using `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` but its not working.

Below is my code.

```
SELECT BOM.STYLE_ID, BOM.SEASON_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BOM.Ad_compo_desc LIKE UPPER('%emb%') THEN 1 ELSE 
           ISNULL(0, 'N/A') END) AS EMBRO,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BOM.Ad_compo_desc LIKE UPPER('%print%') THEN 1 ELSE 
           ISNULL(0, 'N/A') END) AS PRINTING
FROM IPLEXSTY_AD_BOM_DTL BOM
WHERE CONTENT_CLASS = 'ART'
GROUP BY BOM.STYLE_ID, BOM.SEASON_ID;
```

Comment: What is the error/undesired result?

Comment: Also please don't use ALL CAPS. It reads like you're shouting, which doesn't make us want to help you any more than if you just type the title normally.

Comment: Sorry, i 'm just used to it, but I am not shouting :)
Anyway, there's no error thrown but the output does not display N/A, still 0.

Comment: `ISNULL(0, 'N/A')` will always return `0` because `0` is never null? Do you perhaps mean `isnull(BOM.Ad_compo_desc,'n/a')`?

Comment: Also you are using a `sum` statement around your `case statement` - you can't sum `'n/a'` - so that is going to break even if you get the `isnull` working.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, include 1 in quotes('1') which will convert 1 to string then 'N/A' will also load so the column acts as string type, with out converting 1 it will act as an integer type which gives error since you are trying to load 1(integer) and 'N/A'(string) in same column.

```
SELECT BOM.STYLE_ID, BOM.SEASON_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BOM.Ad_compo_desc LIKE UPPER('%emb%') THEN '1' ELSE 
            'N/A' END) AS EMBRO,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BOM.Ad_compo_desc LIKE UPPER('%print%') THEN '1' ELSE 
            'N/A' END) AS PRINTING
FROM IPLEXSTY_AD_BOM_DTL BOM
WHERE CONTENT_CLASS = 'ART'
GROUP BY BOM.STYLE_ID, BOM.SEASON_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, it is better to use `NULL` rather than `'N/A'`.  You would simply do this by removing the `else` clause:

```
   SUM(CASE WHEN BOM.Ad_compo_desc LIKE UPPER('%emb%') THEN 1 END) AS EMBRO,
```

If you really need `'N/A'`, then you need to deal with the fact that the expression must return a string rather than a number.  That requires conversion:

```
   COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),
                    SUM(CASE WHEN BOM.Ad_compo_desc LIKE UPPER('%emb%') THEN 1 END)
                   ), 'N/A'
           ) AS EMBRO,
```

Comment: It throws an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'."

Answer (score 0):

ISNULL and COALESCE works if the first parameter passed is NULL so it will return the second parameter, but if the first parameter is NOT NULL then it will never return the second parameter which is 'N/A' in your case.

```
Declare @firstparam int
set @firstparam =NULL
select ISNULL(@firstparam,'N/A')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use it with `Replace` Function. So it will be

```
SELECT BOM.STYLE_ID, BOM.SEASON_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BOM.Ad_compo_desc LIKE UPPER('%emb%') THEN 1 ELSE 
           Replace(Ad_compo_desc,'0','N/A') END) AS EMBRO,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BOM.Ad_compo_desc LIKE UPPER('%print%') THEN 1 ELSE 
           Replace(Ad_compo_desc,'0','N/A') END) AS PRINTING
FROM IPLEXSTY_AD_BOM_DTL BOM
WHERE CONTENT_CLASS = 'ART'
GROUP BY BOM.STYLE_ID, BOM.SEASON_ID;
```

Here's [a link](https://blog.udemy.com/replace-sql/)